numpy.load using mmap_mode only work in vscode terminal
I am using numpy.load to load .npy data. The code is like this: self.data_memmaps = [np.load(path, mmap_mode='r') for path in data_paths]. If I run python script containing this code in vscode terminal using ssh, everything is OK. However, if i run the same script in other terminal like termius, mobaxterm and etc using ssh, it will produce error: OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files. Anyone has encountered this problem or is there anything wrong with my code?
I have tried termius, mobaxterm and windows terminal ssh, none of them works. Only vscode terminal works.

please post a minimal reproducible example.

For this error OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files, have you tried to increase the limit on the number of open files?

I tried ulimit -n 2048 to increase this, but not works. Finally, I reinstalled windows and vscode on my laptop, reinstalled ubuntu on remote server, then everything is ok.

Try to reinstall VSCode and Ubuntu on the remote server can solve it.
